# How can we generate PDF from selected Standard and Custom objects?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, standard-objects

If i want to generate an Invoice in pdf form for the data that i have enetered in both Standard and Custom fields than what would be the procedure and code to do that?

Answer (score 4):

You can generate a PDF from any object using an VF page with the tag

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf">
```

You will have to design the VF page the way you would want to have your invoice. You can use the standard or custom controllers to capture the data that you need to display on the invoice.

```
<apex:page standardController="Account" renderAs="pdf">

<apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.Styles,'pdf.css')}"/>

<h1>Welcome to Universal Samples!</h1>

<p>Thank you, <b><apex:outputText value=" {!Account.Name}"/></b>, for 
   becoming a new account with Universal Samples.</p>

<p>Your account details are:</p>

<table>
<tr><th>Account Name</th>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!Account.Name}"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr><th>Account Rep</th>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{!Account.Owner.Name}"/></td>
    </tr>
<tr><th>Customer Since</th>
    <td><apex:outputText value="{0,date,long}">
        <apex:param value="{!Account.CreatedDate}"/>
        </apex:outputText></td>
    </tr>
</table>

</apex:page>
```

For more information refer https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_output_pdf_renderas.htm

You can also take a look at this article to generate pdf without coding
https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/generate-pdfs-salesforce-without-writing-any-code-harleen-mann